Bluetooth Support Service doesn't exist in services.msc and paired devices do not connect
I just purchased, received and installed GIGABYTE GC-WBAX2400R, installed drivers and tried to pair my mobile phone to my PC (Windows 10) using that card. I can pair succesfully but then I can't connect any device.
Looking for solutions on Google, many threads suggest to run services.msc, look for Bluetooth Support Service and activate it manually. I tried to do as suggested, sorted the services by name, and it turns out Bluetooth Support Service just isn't there at all.

I googled and couldn't find anyone else with a similar issue, so I'm kinda lost.

Perform normal Windows updates to see if service gets installed.

@MrMoishePippik: I searched for updates and installed it but it didn't fix.
